# Мониторинг событий безопасности (Suricata)

Tags: безопасность, dns

Есть запись  в строчке:
content:"|00 00 FC|";
Что она означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта запись означает, что Suricata будет искать в сетевом трафике последовательность байтов, начинающуюся с 00 00 и заканчивающуюся FC.